# iFrame for implementing Script Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

As I've searched quite a long time for some iFrame settings to make it's content fully responsive for mobile view, I found this solution in stackoverflow.com which works perfectly for me:

```
<iframe src="http://www.test.com/test" style="border:0; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:10%; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%"></iframe>
```

But unfortunately I'm stucked now with implementing another script in iFrame.

Now I would need to get this code fully responsive for mobile device:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    width='100%';
    height='100%';
    border='1';
    shownames='false';
    latitude='37.4460';
    longitude='24.9467';
    zoom='9';
    maptype='0';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.marinetraffic.com/js/embed.js"></script>
```

Any chance to convert that script in the upper iFrame settings which are working perfectly for me?
If not any other suggestions to get it fully responsive, without even a pixel at the sides?

Would be amazing if you could help me, as I've tried for hours now without success.

Thank you guys

Comment: Is the site you are using for the `src` of the iframe one that you have access to edit? If it is, just add the script to that page. Alternatively, If the source of the iframe and the page that the iframe is in are both in same domain (i.e. both of them have a `www.marinetraffic.com` URL, or whatever site you are using) then you can also inject those `script` elements directly into the iframe's document from a script on the base page.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Yes I do have access, so I tried adding the script, but unfortunately it doesn't work. maybe its because the script is missing those iframe settings like      position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;

Comment: Are there similar settings I could add to that script or is it fixed?